# What did I do wrong in this answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I just spent quite a while writing an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184059/how-to-write-log-to-windows-log-file-and-how-to-open-it/1184230#1184230).  Within mins it'd been downvoted and the downvoter didn't leave a comment.

I'm still quite new to SO and still working out the rules.  I guess I've done something wrong - can anyone elaborate?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who replied.  Frankly, I did take it to heart: I assumed that since it had been marked down so quickly and without comment that I'd either broken a rule or done something so stupid it was beneath contempt.  I'll try to be more thick-skinned.

Comment: Nah, my answers randomly get downvoted too at times. It's real easy to tell when someone is trying to bump their answer because you'll see other legitimate answers with a down vote as well. I don't think this is such a bad thing. The user is so convinced their answer is correct they're willing to spend some of their rep to move their answer up. That's fine. The community ultimately decides.

Comment: Seems to be a plus 10 now... ???

Comment: @INTERESTING Its 10 years later. A lot can happen in that time.

Answer (score 8):

You can't take down voting too personally.  Sometimes there is something wrong with the and people will down vote it because of that.  Other times, it may be because someone doesn't understand what you are saying and down votes too quickly or just disagrees with an approach you took.  There are other times when someone just wants to see their answer above other people and will down vote you to put below them.  If I had to guess if was probably the second one.

Briefly looking at it, it looks like the answer is through and complete.  Simply put, if you try and figure out the reason why one of your question gets down voted every time, you are going to drive yourself nuts.  You just have to accept the fact that some people like punishing others for no apparent reason.

Comment: +1, Step 1: accept the fact that some people like punishing others for no apparent reason.  Step 2: Bliss

Comment: I think you hit it on the head: The approach is probably the cause here. Going through the Enterprise Library for something that's easily done with `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` is a bit of overkill, and I'd be willing to bet that's what was being downvoted.

Comment: "Going through the Enterprise Library for something that's easily done with System.Diagnostics.EventLog is a bit of overkill" is exactly the sort of useful comment that a downvoter should post to the answer. Granted, if that comment was given, we might not have had the oppo here to gain points...

Comment: @akf: Yes, bet these are *meta points*! (does that make them worth more or leass than regular SO points?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any real problems here. Certainly, there's nothing there that would cause *me* to downvote you.

Maybe the downvoter is frightened of XML. There's certainly a lot of XML configuration there. I know Enterprise Library, and am not offended by XML, so it's no big deal to me.

You might want to replace the XML with a screen shot of the graphical editor.

Comment: Yesterday I dreamed that I was surrounded by pointy brackets, and my schema was invalid, and suddenly an XSLT appeared and started transforming me... which is when I woke up. Damn XML nightmares!!!

Answer (score 1):

One reason *could* be that people thought you were not really aswering the question. I noticed this a few times with questions that were not formulated very well. This can lead to different understandings of what the OP wants, and subsequently to a disagreement on the usefulness of your answer.

Something else can cause confusion in such a case (which is *not* the case in the question you are referring to): Edits to the question, in an attempt to clarify it. I have given answers to questions that asked for specific things, later someone edited the question and used other terms to describe what was asked for, which made my answer look completely off topic. There's not really much you can do about it. Except, [as Kevin points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9717/what-did-i-do-wrong-in-this-answer/9720#9720), not to care too much about the downvote ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you got downvoted (I'm an ignoramus on the topic you posted about).

What I can say is that your answer was verbose.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me yesterday, and ended up deleting my answer.

The problem is that we sometimes get trapped answering trap questions. The question referenced is not well formed and is a 3 for the price of one question.

3 for the price of one questions are risky beasts, for example, the top voted question doe not address this sub question properly (IMHO):

> I need to see this log file, how to
>   open it?

This could imply that the OP is looking for a gui of sorts, like the windows event viewer.

Careful not too get trapped answering 3 in one questions too thoroughly, you may be answering the wrong question.

Answer (score -2):

I am having a similar issue, and in fact my answer to you is, as far as I can tell, "like" the one that, in this case, quickly got me -3 out of the gate upon signing up with this question and answer (hopefully, this URL will work:)

[How to cope with choking when playing games?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106207/how-to-cope-with-choking-when-playing-games/351986#351986)

In this case, it is about "choking" at video games (as in screwing up under performance pressure) and I thought I gave the best answer I could as an avid rhythm video gamer. It's still a rather subjective question that is very hard, if not impossible, to give a "perfect" answer to.

I really feel like I should be able to post a similar "problem" I have in my answer with SOME knowledge about it, so that, while I may not be able to provide a complete solution, I can at least give SOME hints to some people.

Like what was said before, some people with reputation are willing to spend it just to bump their own posts upwards. Perhaps I got 1-3 of those people downvoting me - I don't know.

But this does convince me, as well as to second here to others, not to take it personally if they don't leave a comment with it.

Plus, there is the fact that you need 15 Reputation to upvote at all in a way that shows... I do think this blocks many users who get perfect answers from giving upvotes they really feel like giving!!